# Number of variables pass to function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I don't ever have to write anything in VB.NET.

But I am passing variables named "name" to a function and sometimes it may be 1 name or 2 names, etc. I want to check in the function if its only 1 name don't add a comma, if it's 2 names add a comma. Is there a way to get how many "names" there are?

EDIT: Added my ode to make my question a little more clear. sorry for not doing it before.

My Code:

```
Public Function GenerateCSV(byval str as string, byval str1 as string, byval str2 as string, byval GrpName as string) 
  IF GroupName <> GrpName THEN
    GroupName = GrpName
    CSVString = ""
  END IF
  IF str = ""
    CSVString = ""
  ELSE
    CSVString = CSVString & str & ", " & str1 & ", " & str2 & ", " 
  END IF
  return CSVString
End function
```

Thanks!

Comment: I responded to your edit. But I do have a question now, is this for any number of names or is there a maximum?

Comment: Thanks. It could be any number of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass them as a List or array. With these, you can get the number of items and do whatever processing you need to do.

```
Public Function DoSomething(names As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
    'Include this if there is a possibility of an names containing nothing
    If names.Count = 0 Then
        Return ""
    End If

    Dim csvString As String = names(0)

    'First one is already added, loop through remaining
    For i As Integer = 1 To (names.Count - 1)
        csvString = csvString + ", " + names(i)
    Next

    Return csvString
End Function
```

You would preferably use IEnumerable which can take arrays or list among other things. You could use IList(Of String) or String() if you wanted though.

Comment: Syntactically, shouldn't your parameter be IEnumerable(Of String)?

Comment: Yes it should. I'm more of a C# guy. Thanks. Fixing.

Comment: As am I -- I really didn't know if VB supported that syntax as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your handleing the name variable, but if your using an array this could work...

```
string FullName

If name[1] != "" Then
   FullName = name[0] + "," + name[1]
End If
```

I'm also not sure how you want the 'name' variable output, but this will concat both names together and separate them with a comma. The output on FullName would be "Name,Name"

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

Edited following clarification in the question of the function inputs.

(I'm not a VB person but) something like:-

```
Public Function GenerateCSV(byval str as string, byval str1 as string, byval str2     as     string, byval GrpName as string)
    Dim strAll As String
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outStr As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    strAll = str + " " + str1 + " " + str2
    strAll = strAll.Trim()
    strArr = strAll.Split(" ")
    For i = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
        if i > 0 then
           outStr.Append(",")
        End If
    outStr.Append(strArr(i))
    Next
    return outStr.ToString
End Function
```

I'm sure a VB guy could pretty this up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ParamArray to process a variable number of parameters, then you can do:

```
Private Function ProcessNames(ByVal ParamArray asNames() As String) As String

    Dim sbName As New System.Text.StringBuilder(100)

    If asNames IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each sName As String In asNames
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sName) Then
                If sbName.Length <> 0 Then
                    sbName.Append(", ")
                End If
                sbName.Append(sName)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return sbName.ToString
End Function
```

Which would be called like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Debug.WriteLine(ProcessNames("name1", "name2"))
    Debug.WriteLine(ProcessNames("name3"))

End Sub
```

And produce output as:

```
name1, name2
name3
```

ProcessNames can also be used to process a string containing multiple names separated by some delimter such as a space:

```
    Debug.WriteLine(ProcessNames("name1 name2".Split(" "c)))
    Debug.WriteLine(ProcessNames("name3".Split(" "c)))
```

Produces the output:

```
name1, name2
name3
```